# What is the Java 8 Stream API equivalent for LINQ Join?

Tags: java, c#, .net, linq, join

In C#/.Net it is possible to join IEnumerable sequences with the extension method Enumerable.Join in a SQL 'JOIN ... ON' way.

Is there something similar in Java 8 (Stream API)? Or what is the best way to simulate Enumerable.Join?

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Almost certainly you'd have to dump both streams into maps on the specified key, and then join the maps directly.  Java streams aren't really designed to be combined in any way but concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any existing equivalent, but the below method should work:

```
public static <Outer, Inner, Key, Result> Stream<Result> join(
        Stream<Outer> outer, Stream<Inner> inner,
        Function<Outer, Key> outerKeyFunc,
        Function<Inner, Key> innerKeyFunc,
        BiFunction<Outer, Inner, Result> resultFunc) {

    //Collect the Inner values into a list as we'll need them repeatedly
    List<Inner> innerList = inner.collect(Collectors.toList());

    //matches will store the matches between inner and outer
    final Map<Outer, List<Inner>> matches = new HashMap<>();

    //results will be used to collect the results in
    final List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();


    outer.forEach(o -> innerList
            .stream()
            //Filter to get those Inners for which the Key equals the Key of this Outer
            .filter(i -> innerKeyFunc.apply(i).equals(outerKeyFunc.apply(o)))
            .forEach(i -> {
                if (matches.containsKey(o)) {
                    //This Outer already had matches, so add this Inner to the List
                    matches.get(o).add(i);
                } else {
                    //This is the first Inner to match this Outer, so create a List
                    List<Inner> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(i);
                    matches.put(o, list);
                }
            }));

    matches.forEach((out, in) -> in.stream()
            //Map each (Outer, Inner) pair to the appropriate Result...
            .map(i -> resultFunc.apply(out, i))
            //...and collect them
            .forEach(res -> results.add(res)));

    //Return the result as a Stream, like the .NET method does (IEnumerable)
    return results.stream();
}
```

I only did a brief test of the code using the following inputs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "d").stream();
    Stream<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4).stream();
    Stream<String> results = join(strings, ints, 
            Function.identity(),
            str    -> Integer.parseInt(str, 16) - 9, 
            (o, i) -> "Outer: " + o + ", Inner: " + i);
    results.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r));
}
```

- The `int`s are their own keys, so no transformation
- The `Strings` are mapped to `int`s according to their hex value - 9
- (The elements match if the `int` values are equal, as per default)
- Matching pairs are put into a `String`

The following (correct) results are printed:

```
Outer: a, Inner: 1
Outer: b, Inner: 2
Outer: c, Inner: 3
Outer: d, Inner: 4
Outer: e, Inner: 5
Outer: f, Inner: 6
```

More in-depth testing will be needed, of course, but I believe this implementation to be correct. It could probably be more efficient as well, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

[join is just syntactic sugar for `Stream.flatMap()` as explained in this article](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/08/13/common-sql-clauses-and-their-equivalents-in-java-8-streams/). Consider this example:

```
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(2, 2, 4, 7);

l1.stream()
  .flatMap(i1 -> l2.stream()
                   .filter(i2 -> i1.equals(i2)))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result is:

```
2
2
4
```

In the above example, `flatMap()` corresponds to `(INNER) JOIN` whereas the `filter()` operation of the nested stream corresponds to the `ON` clause.

[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) is a library that implements `innerJoin()` and other join types to abstract over this, e.g. also to buffer stream contents in case you want to join two `Stream` instances, instead of two `Collection` instances. With jOOλ, you would then write:

```
Seq<Integer> s1 = Seq.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
Seq<Integer> s2 = Seq.of(2, 2, 4, 7);

s1.innerJoin(s2, (i1, i2) -> i1.equals(i2))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

... which prints (the output are tuples, which is more like SQL's semantics semantics):

```
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(4, 4)
```

(disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Answer (score 1):

I also came from C# and missed that feature. One big advantage would be to have readable code by expressing intention. So I wrote my own [streamjoin](https://github.com/simomat/streamjoin) which works like C# Enumerable.Join(). Plus: it tolerates null-keys.

```
Stream<BestFriends> bestFriends = 
 join(listOfPersons.stream())
  .withKey(Person::getName)
  .on(listOfDogs.stream())
  .withKey(Dog::getOwnerName)
  .combine((person, dog) -> new BestFriends(person, dog))
  .asStream();
```